# Linux or Android app for non-intrusive recording

Tags: android, linux-distribution, voice-recording, audio-recording

I record all my works progress since I am not good at taking notes. However, most software that I have tried are blinking or lots of pop-up dialogues, which makes me aware and more stressed.
I am looking for both Android and/or Linux application that would be able to record sound and possibly video without much distraction.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post an include an "example setup" (or "practical use example"), explaining what it should achieve? E.g. "I'm drilling a hole to the wall and want the software to monitor the progress, so I can later see/hear what I've done and how. For this I just want to push 'start' and later 'stop' in the software after directing the cam/mike accordingly". This would give us a clearer picture of what the software should be like. Thanks!